# video capture module not working properly in an opencv project

Tags: python, opencv, pip, video-capture, python-module

```
import face_recognition
import cv2
import numpy as np
import csv
import os
from datetime import datetime

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

tata_img = face_recognition.load_image_file("photos/tata.jpg")
tata_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(tata_img)[0]

modi_img = face_recognition.load_image_file("photos/modi.jpg")
modi_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(modi_img)[0]

ambani_img = face_recognition.load_image_file("photos/ambani.jpg")
ambani_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(ambani_img)[0]

known_face_encoding = [tata_encoding, modi_encoding, ambani_encoding]
known_face_names = ["tata", "modi", "ambani"]

students = known_face_names.copy()

face_locations = []
face_encodings = []
face_names = []
s=True

now = datetime.now()
current_date = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

f = open(current_date+'.csv','w+',newline = '')
lnwriter = csv.writer(f)

while True:
    _,frame = video_capture.read()
    small_frame = cv2.resize(frame,(0,0),fx=0.25,fy=0.25)
    rgb_small_frame = small_frame[:,:,::-1]
    if s:
        face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_small_frame)
        face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_small_frame,face_locations)
        face_names = []
        for face_encoding in face_encodings:
            matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encoding,face_encoding)
            name = ""
            face_distance = face_recognition.face_distance(known_face_encoding,face_encoding)
            best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distance)
            if matches[best_match_index]:
                name = known_face_names[best_match_index]

            face_names.append(name)
            if name in known_face_names:
                if name in students:
                    students.remove(name)
                    print(students)
                    current_time = now.strftime("%H-%M-%S")
                    lnwriter.writerow([name, current_time])

    cv2.imshow("attendence system", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
f.close()
```

_,frame = video_capture.read()

video_capture.release()

these two lines are not working. I've downloaded the opencv-python module as well as opencv-contrib-python module. Still the codé isn't working. The main problem showing is that the webcam turns on but can't read anything. it keeps open untill I close the program.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `ret ,frame = video_capture.read()` check `ret` value, is it `True` always?